# How can I generate dashboard report according to my Selenium Script in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am executing my selenium script using Selenium/WebDriver sampler and after the execution of multiple threads, it has been only showing the overall results for all the users. But I want to know the particular time taken by a particular URL that is moving from one to another mapping that I have written in my Selenium Script. Currently, it will show like this :

[image]

**But my requirement is to get a detailed report for each request. Currently, I have used two thread Groups in which I have used 5 Threads for each group so the total becomes 10 users that will run parallelly and I have to get the detailed report for each user in the dashboard. For more information please see the below script where all data comes from a CSV File.**

> My Selenium Script is:(Using JavaScript)

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://tst-crm.lifec.com/');
var username = WDS.args[0];
var password = WDS.args[1];
var msisdn = WDS.args[2];

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(username);
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(password);
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@value='Login']")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("userDropdown")).click();

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("(//*[@id='toolbar-search-input'])[3]")).sendKeys(msisdn);
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("(//*[@type='submit'])[3]")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Lead Generator')][1]/following::*[6]")).click();

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@href='#orderSummary']")).click();

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'View Bill Info')]")).click();

WDS.browser.navigate().back();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@href='#customerDetails']")).click();

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Update Account Password')]")).click();

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("userDropdown")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Logout')]")).click();
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

**My requirement to get the detailed report of every request that I have written in selenium/Webdriver sampler as shared above. Can anyone please help me out from this?**

Comment: If you use scenarios in separate thread group your result will be displayed properly in report. It seems that you have used this in a single thread group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your script into several WebDriver Samplers like:

1. First sampler: Open page:

   ```
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('https://tst-crm.lifec.com/');
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
   ```
2. Second sampler: Login:

   ```
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   var username = WDS.args[0];
   var password = WDS.args[1];
   WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(username);
   WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(password);
   WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@value='Login']")).click();
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
   ```
3. etc.

You can also use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) somewhere in WebDriver Sampler's label in order to get user-specific timings like:

```
Open Page - User: ${__threadNum}
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! That's what I needed, and instead of `__threadNum() function`, I have directly use the **${USERNAME}** in my sampler name that is coming from my CSV Data config file  so now the results are shown in a sequence manner.

Comment: Hello sir, in this case I'm getting the particular user details ,,,,,but I didn't get the url report in which user was navigated to. I want to show the url report also in which how much time it will take by the url.